# Issue in processing multipart-form data using aws lambda(Ruby)

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipartform-data, file-handling

I am using `Aws Lambda` to process `multipart-form` data and extract attachments and then I want to upload these attachments to `Aws S3`. What's happening here is the file gets corrupt.

What I am doing is I am extracting attachment `file_string` as a string and then I am writing it to a file in `/tmp` folder.

```
File.open('/tmp/file_name', 'wb') do |f|
  f << file_string
end
```

I checked the file content and compared it with the original file. Some of the characters in the file are replaced by the replacement character.

```
�PNG

IHDRX�{�`)iCCPICC ProfileX��yTM�n��&sFr�Yr�9�ʒ3�$AAD��HDD�H    ��
```

But the actual file content is like this.

```
?PNG

IHDRX?{?`)iCCPICC ProfileX??yTM?n??&sFr?Yr?9?ʒ3?$AAD??HDD?H    ?
```

And this is from lambda cloud-watch logs which I used to check the content of the received string on lambda

```
�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0001-\u0000\u0000\u0001-\b\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000j=��\u0000\u0000\u0002\u001cPLTE\u0000\u0000\u
```

Can anybody explain what I doing wrong?

or Is it the problem with lambda environment?

Comment: all I can think is encoding, try `file_string.encoding` to see what it is using, maybe it is wrong.

Comment: I checked the encoding and it is UTF-8.

Comment: Hi @Avinash142857, I am facing the same issue. Did you find a resolution to this? if yes, kindly update.